# What are the differences between Java Virtual Machine (JVM) and Java Middleware?

Tags: jvm, middleware

What are the concentual differences between Java Virtual Machine (JVM) and Java Middleware?

Comment: Middleware is more oriented to distributed environment. It is more general term, there are many types of middleware.

Answer (score 1):

JVM is a runtime to execute Java (and a few other languages these days) bytecode.

Java Middleware are frameworks for technologies like EJB, RMI, Corba etc. Essentially technologies which might not have anything to do with Java specifically, but is supported by Java.

Comment: Thanks tinkerbeast!  Can we call a JVM to be a middleware ?

Comment: @Shan it's hard to say. I think of midddle-ware as something (substantial) that sits between the OS and application level code. In that sense you can call JVM a middle-ware I guess. However I would personally never call a runtime (JVM, .NET, AIR etc) a middle-ware.